# How to force a hyperlink inside IFrame to open into a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

My code is pasted below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head>
<base target="_blank">
</head>
<body> 

<div style="border: 2px solid #D5CC5A; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 800px; max-height: 1750px;">
<base target="_blank" />
<iframe name="myIframe" scrolling="auto" src="http://example.com" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -30px; height: 4000px; margin-top: -900px; width: 850px;">
</iframe>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have tried with target attribute but it's not worked. Please help.

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried, there's no links on the provided example. Also explain the issue in details, "_not worked_" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: "How to force a hyperlink `inside IFrame` to open into a new window?" -- First thing first, you cannot change anything in to iFrame if you don't have access to the original resource. Second thing, the question is very unclear to understand, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head>
<base target="_blank">
</head>
<body> 

<div style="border: 2px solid #D5CC5A; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 800px; max-height: 1750px;">
<base target="_blank" />
<iframe name="myIframe" scrolling="auto" src="http://example.com" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -30px; height: 1000px; width: 850px;">
</iframe>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I took out the value of margin-top: -900px; to get the required document in the view area.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the margin does not have an affect to the target of an hyperlink.